# How to limit the number of items to enter metadata on when importing from GeoServer into GeoNetwork

Tags: data-management, geoserver, geonetwork, metadata

We are a library looking at using GeoServer and GeoNetwork as the basis of a GIS repository/catalog. When we enter layers in GeoServer and then harvest using GeoNetwork, we end up with a large number of layers for which we have to enter metadata in GeoNetwork. University of Virgina have a tool that they use to group layers, and then publish the record for the group to GeoNetwork, but I was wondering if other people had come up with solutions that they would be willing to share.

Comment: Hi Garey, could you help me understand your question a bit better?GeoNetwork is requiring entry of metadata on a per-layer basis, where you'd like to provide metadata at a higher level? How are you producing the metadata documents?

Answer (score 1):

I don't need it for the moment but it seems Geonode is a way to get a solution
(http://projects.opengeo.org/CAPRA/wiki/CSW_client_implementation_guidelines)

I've only heard of this project. If someone have more informations, I will be happy to get them too.

Official Geonode website on http://geonode.org/about/

Comment: Looks like a decent answer AND it's the only answer :)  +100